# How to retrieve the post URL for a Facebook or Twitter post using SLComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, social-framework, slcomposeviewcontroller

After sending a post to either Facebook or Twitter with SLComposeViewControllerResult, is it possible to get a URL of that post?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is **not possible** till current implementation of SLComposeViewController.

Because SLComposeViewControllerResult only gives limited options.

Ref [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SLComposeViewControllerResult)

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the help.